# Add two buttons if another button has been pressed

Tags: java, swift, button, actionlistener

```
b.button1 = new JButton("Deal");
b.button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //code
            b.button2 = new JButton("Hit");
            panel.add(b.button2);
             panel.validate();
            b.button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           //code
        }     
    });

           b.button3 = new JButton("Stay");
            panel.add(b.button3);
            panel.validate();
            b.button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //code
            }
        }     
    });
```

So I want The Buttons `Hit` and `Stay` to be added as soon as the `Deal` button has been pressed. I searched for a solution and found the `panel.validate()` method. I used it but now if I press the `Deal` button it only adds the `Hit` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the buttons before and make them "hidden". If you press the button, you can "show" them to include them.